# Bare minimum google places api fields to have react-geosuggest work?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api

Google has changed their maps/places api pricing in the last year of so. I am looking to include a autocomplete input in a project. I'm mostly looking for home addresses (it's real estate related) and so I don't think I need the majority of the extra service fields (places details, atmospheric, etc)

I'm using [react-geosuggest](https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) which has a prop `placeDetailFields`  that allows the following:

> Type: Array Default: null
>
> By default Google returns all fields when getting place details which can impact billing. You can optionally pass an array of fields to include in place results to limit what is returned and potentially reduce billing impact. geometry will always be added as we depend on the location for the suggest selection.

Because address_components can differ between calls, what is the bare minimum fields one should call to end up with a common postal address such as

```
    lat: String
    lng: String
    placeId: String
    fullAddress: String
    postal: String
    country: String
    state: String
    city: String
    street: String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places Details service must be called in order to get information about the selected place from Autocomplete suggestions.

[Basic Data fields](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields#basic) have [no additional costs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#basic-data) and include the following fields:

> address_component, adr_address, formatted_address, geometry, icon,
>   name, permanently_closed, photo, place_id, plus_code, type, url,
>   utc_offset, vicinity

To get the lat/lng use `geometry.location`.

To get the place id use `place_id`.

To get the full address use `formatted_address`.

To get the postal code use `address_components.types["postal_code"]`.

To get the country use `address_components.types["country"]`.

To get the state use `address_components.types["administrative_area_level_1"]`.

To get the city use `address_components.types["locality"]`.

To get the street use `address_components.types["route"]`.

Google's Autocomplete + Places Details + Fields examples can be found in [these](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) [links](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

**Note:** even though these are all Basic Data fields, Places Details and Places Autocomplete are both billable services. To prevent getting charged at all, look into setting [daily quota limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_cap).

Hope this helps!